# How to remove the vertical scrollbar SyntaxHighlighter block?

Tags: css, joomla, scrollbar, syntax-highlighting

I am newbie in Web-developing and possibly has a primary question.
I have installed Joomla 2.5 CMS on my site, downloaded, installed and turned on the [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) plugin. Then enabled the `bash` syntax and added nothing more the following code to my page

```
<pre class="brush: bash">$ uname -a
Linux laptop 2.6.32-41-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 27 22:22:09 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
$</pre>
```

I got this result

[image: vertical scrollbar in SyntaxHighlighter's block]

It is OK but I have no idea why the highlighted vertical scrollbar appears. It scrolls only for a one or two pixels. So, what I have tried is to add a following code to the beginning of my template's `CSS` file

```
.syntaxhighlighter,
.syntaxhighlighter div,
.syntaxhighlighter code,
.syntaxhighlighter table,
.syntaxhighlighter table td,
.syntaxhighlighter table tr,
.syntaxhighlighter table tbody {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

It does not helped me and I think the problem is deeper. Do you have any ideas about how to remove this vertical scrollbar?

**Update** If I use the `!important` declaration in template's `CSS` the scrollbar dissappear but the block with highlighted code behaves very strange on page scaling.

Answer (score 27):

You can add the following style to remove the vertical scroll bar and add horizontal one only when needed:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .syntaxhighlighter { 
     overflow-y: hidden !important; 
     overflow-x: auto !important; 
  }
</style>
```

Comment: If you use a seperate CSS file, you first have to remove all "!important" parts for all *overflow* properties in `scCore.cs` to get this answer to work

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the example and found that there is a vertical scroll in that as well.  When I inspected  `"syntaxhighlighter  javascript"` itself had an overflow.  Check if you have included the code after or before you included the css

Answer (score 0):

syntaxhighlighter has `overflow: auto` as default style (see following css snippet in shCoreDefault.css). That's why we have to set `overflow-y:hidden !important` when we don't like vertical scrollbar. But we don't need set `overflow-x: auto` anymore. It's already there.

```
.syntaxhighlighter {
    font-size: 1em !important;
    margin: 1em 0 !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

You can see syntaxhighlighter has already used '!important', that's why, you would find different browsers has different result. On my experience, in Firefox, I got the intended result: vertical scrollbar being hidden. But in Chrome, scrollbar is still over there.

In order have a higher priority of my defined class, I prefix some other scope selector, like the container's id or class.

```
ContainerId .syntaxhighlighter {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove your vertical scrollbar for SyntaxHighlighter in your website you can use the below code snippet in your `<head>...</head>` section of your page.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .syntaxhighlighter table td.code .container {
  position: relative !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px !important;
}
</style>
```

Hope this code snippet helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to remove a *horizontal* scroll bar, this was what finally worked for me, taking inspiration from John Yin's post above. No sub-set of the below worked in-and-of itself.

```
/* .post class is on high-level div */
.post .syntaxhighlighter {
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    overflow-y: visible !important;
    overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```